# cifs mounts with wrong uid, gid (buster -> bullseye)

Tags: cifs, smbclient

## Context :

Existing debian buster acting as CIFS / SMB client

## Problem :

After migration from buster to debian bullseye, mount point is still working but uid and gid option are ignored at the filesystem level (but are correct within the `mount` command's output)

`cat /etc/fstab` :

```
...
//192.168.0.1/data    /mnt/data    cifs    _netdev,nodev,nosuid,noexec,credentials=/etc/credentials,uid=myuser,gid=mygroup,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,vers=1.0     0       0
...
```

`mount` : (uid 101 is myuser and gid 101 is mygroup so here values are correct)

```
...
//192.168.0.1/data on /mnt/data type cifs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=cifslogin,uid=101,forceuid,gid=101,forcegid,addr=192.168.0.1,soft,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,_netdev)
...
```

`ls -la /mnt/data` :

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 1100 users    0 Sep 13 00:01 .
...
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I found out that there exist two options `forceuid` and `forcegid` that can be leveraged to ignore a samba server's unix extension.

`cat /etc/fstab` :

```
...
//192.168.0.1/data    /mnt/data    cifs    _netdev,nodev,nosuid,noexec,credentials=/etc/credentials,uid=myuser,forceuid,gid=mygroup,forcegid,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,vers=1.0     0       0
...
```